# Is there any way to output the sql generated by a propel select in symfony?

Tags: symfony1, propel

I want to output the query generated by a symfony propel select for testing purposes. Is there any way to do this? I know I can use the sf_debug bar, but sometimes I need to see the statement in a situation where the sf_debug bar hasn't loaded yet, or isn't going to load at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timmow is right that there is a `Criteria::toString()` method, but it's not the magic `_toString()` method that's automatically called when the object is referenced as a string.

If you want to see the SQL you have to explicitly call `Criteria::toString()`.

```
$c = new Criteria();
// HERE: add criteria
// what's it do?
echo $c->toString(); // oh, that's what it does
```

Comment: Interesting - it "sorta" works - I get this output for the page I happen to be working on:

Criteria: SQL (may not be complete): SELECT FROM ORDER BY ugc_question.LAST_RESPONSE_AT DESC Params:

Comment: also, the above code snippet should say echo $c->toString(); // oh...

(not $c->getString(); )

Answer (score 0):

Propel Criteria objects have a [toString](http://propel.phpdb.org/docs/api/1.3/runtime/propel-util/Criteria.html#methodtoString) method, so you should simply be able to echo / var_dump / log to a file the criteria object you are interested in

Answer (score 0):

It also might be helpful to take a look at Day 6 of the Jobeet Tutorial, [Debugging Propel generated SQL](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_2/Propel/en/06#chapter_06_debugging_propel_generated_sql). If you're in the debug environment, the raw queries are output to the log files. Not 100% sure as I use Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the generated SQL statement that way after you've build the criteria :

```
    $params= array();
    $resulting_sql_statement = BasePeer::createSelectSql($criteria,$params);
```